# I want to add a button to a spreadsheet that will 'make a copy' and move to a specified folder

Tags: file, button, google-sheets

I have found similar questions and have tried using the scripts but none of them work for me.

I have a created an order form using Google Sheets and once we have filled it in for a customer order, I want to click on a button that makes a copy of the sheet using the filename of order ID, First Name and Surname and then storing it in a folder called November Orders etc. I want to attach the script to a button. I have created the button but cannot get a script to work. I keep getting error messages such as getrange is null or folder ID is not right. I'm pulling my hair out here! It's quite time consuming to go to file, make a copy, paste in the order ID, type the name in and then choose the destination folder so I want a button on the sheet that just does it! It will also be better for the technophobes in the office who have never used sheets or excel.

All help welcome! If someone could paste the actual script that I need, that would be awesome!

[Current form with reset button but want a save button too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u55gT.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the script that you are trying currently?  Can you post the exact error message that you're getting?

Comment: Hi Thomas, the script I tried was this one: function saveAsSpreadsheet(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('Samson!A9:B9');
  sheet.setNamedRange('buildingNameAddress', range);
  var TestRange = sheet.getRangeByName('buildingNameAddress').getValues(); 
  Logger.log(TestRange); 
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("Test File", destFolder); 
}

Comment: The buildingname bit confused me as I don't think I need that? and I don't understand the test range part either. Sorry for being such a noob!

Comment: Hi @NicolaForster, an answer below was already posted. Feel free to accept and upvote the answer if you feel it was useful to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the script below to achieve your target. Please see comments(//) for my explanation for every part of the script and its functionalities.

```
function makeCopy() {
  // Make sure the script your make copy button is running is "makeCopy"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // No columns/rows are present in the image so I used sample cells
  // Update the cells below (B1, B2, B3) to correspond with the needed values
  var firstName = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var lastName = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var orderID = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  
  // Filename format was my idea
  // No specifics were mentioned so create a format what you think is best
  // The sample here is <lastName>_<firstName>_<orderID> based on what variables you gave
  var fileName = lastName + "_" + firstName + "_" + orderID;
  
  // Exit function if one of the variables for the filename is blank
  if ( !lastName || !firstName || !orderID ) { 
    return; 
  }
  
  // Update folderID with your folder's ID. 
  // Can be found in the URL when the drive is currently visited. 
  // Everything after "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/" is the folderID
  var folderID = "14oxtQIqRenG2l7fTk-I7fz7UunjxB64a";
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(fileName, destFolder); 
}

function reset() {
  // Make sure the script your reset button is running is "reset"
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // No columns/rows are present in the image so I used sample cells
  // Add/Update the cells below (B1, B2, B3) to correspond with the needed values to be reset
  var firstName = sheet.getRange("B3").clear();
  var lastName = sheet.getRange("B2").clear();
  var orderID = sheet.getRange("B1").clear();
}
```

After replicating the script, go to your spreadsheet file and create a reset button to clear all the data you have in the spreadsheet. You can follow this link for the instruction on how to add a button in the spreadsheet, as this is also my reference: https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-sheets-button/

Comment: Oh my goodness, wow! You are a superstar! It works beautifully, thank you so much, I'm beyond grateful! :)

Comment: @NicolaForster, Feel free to upvote the answer above too if you feel it. Thanks

Comment: Hi I have upvoted but as Monique is a new user, it says it isn't publicly displayed?

Comment: Hi @NicolaForster, you can refer to this link on how to upvote an answer: 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=There%20is%20an%20up%20&%20down,refers%20to%20downvote/negative%20voting

Thanks a lot! :)